# Alternative for python-daemon on Windows

Tags: python, python-openid, python-daemon

I'm trying to use a python library (python_openid) which depends upon python-daemon. The latter [does not appear to work on Windows](https://bitbucket.org/danjac/flask-mail/issue/10/cannot-use-on-windows).

What alternatives have I got (short of installing Linux)?

Comment: Did you try just installing `python_openid` without installing `python-daemon`? It's likely that you can do that without issues.

Comment: Assuming you meant `python-openid` with a hyphen, I checked its [README](https://github.com/openid/python-openid) and it doesn't say anything about requiring `python-daemon`...